# Is it possible to develop an app for a just a few people?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

I am looking for a way that I can develop an app cheaply for a very specific use. 
Specifically, I would like to create an game that can be played online between different phones.

I have some coding and development experience, and I would like to make the app iOS compatible (initially... open to Android integration later on).
Is anyone aware of a way to make an app without paying $99+ a year to be deployed on the app store? I simply need to make it available to approximately 15 people, and am uninterested in making any money or widely distributing the app. 
Many of the target audience are in low-income areas of the world and have very limited access to computers, so a mobile application is likely my only option.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have done research into Apple developer accounts, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs. I have also looked into making an Ad-Hoc account app, but can't find a lot of info on the feasibility of this.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is what are the game performance requirements?

If it is a simple game, using a [Javascript game engine](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) may be a better option as it can be hosted on a server (and viewed in a browser) to start with, and later bundled in a progressive web app with [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com).

Comment: I hadn't thought about that... Thanks for the advice! It's a fairly simple card game, no need for fancy graphics or anything so this may be a good option

Comment: In that case it may be a very good option. Have a look at Progressive Web App (PWA). Nowadays you can develop a website and bookmark it so it appears as an app on your phone. When you launch it that way it will remove the browser toolbars and leave the whole space to your app. You can define the icons and stuff in your manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I think this question should be moved to a different Stack Exchange website.

Anyway, if you want to distribute your app to iOS real devices through the App Store, you will have to pay the $99 yearly membership.
There is also a [free Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/). I never tried it and I think you need physical access to the devices on which you want to load the app. But I could be wrong and maybe you'll have access to TestFlight. If you do have access to TestFlight the only disadvantage is that you'll have to re-publish your app from time to time when the testing period for one version is over. Try it!

> iOS device and low-income don't really fit together ;-).

On Android, it is much more affordable even with the use of the Play store. If it hasn't change much it is a one time $25 fee and that's it. You can do Alpha/Beta and Production releases.
Regarding your requirements it is the best platform because the devices are generally cheaper.

Comment: My bad! Wasn't sure if this was the right place or not, but I appreciate your help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

To developp on Android, it's free, you just pay if you want to publish the app on store.

For ios, you can't do anything without creating a developper account, so pay $99.
You're always able to use a cross-platform langage (react native, flutter for ex.) but as soon as you want to deploy on real apple device, you'll need to pay.

Comment: For a couple of years now, you can build and load apps onto your own personal iOS devices using Xcode by just being a Registered Apple Developer (free), you only need to be a Apple Developer Program member ($99 a year) if you want to distribute.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like my best option right now might be to develop the app for personal use and pay the $99 once I get it up and working...